# Addressing polynomial multiplication and division "overflow" issue

Tags: numpy, floating-accuracy, polynomials, polynomial-math

I have a list of the coefficient to degree 1 polynomials, with `a[i][0]*x^1 + a[i][1]`

```
a = np.array([[ 1.        , 77.48514702],
          [ 1.        ,  0.        ],
             [ 1.        ,  2.4239275 ],
           [ 1.        ,  1.21848739],
            [ 1.        ,  0.        ],
            [ 1.        ,  1.18181818],
           [ 1.        ,  1.375     ],
           [ 1.        ,  2.        ],
          [ 1.        ,  2.        ],
          [ 1.        ,  2.        ]])
```

And running into issues with the following operation,

```
np.polydiv(reduce(np.polymul, a), a[0])[0] != reduce(np.polymul, a[1:])
```

where

```
In [185]: reduce(np.polymul, a[1:])
Out[185]:
array([  1.        ,  12.19923307,  63.08691612, 179.21045388,
       301.91486027, 301.5756213 , 165.35814595,  38.39582615,
         0.        ,   0.        ])
```

and

```
In [186]: np.polydiv(reduce(np.polymul, a), a[0])[0]
Out[186]:
array([ 1.00000000e+00,  1.21992331e+01,  6.30869161e+01,  1.79210454e+02,
        3.01914860e+02,  3.01575621e+02,  1.65358169e+02,  3.83940472e+01,
        1.37845155e-01, -1.06809521e+01])
```

First of all the remainder of `np.polydiv(reduce(np.polymul, a), a[0])` is way bigger than 0, `827.61514239` to be exact, and secondly, the last two terms to quotient should be 0, but way larger from 0. `1.37845155e-01, -1.06809521e+01`.

I'm wondering what are my options to improve the accuracy?

Comment: How are the polynomials represented; in `1, 2`, is `1` the coefficient of 1 and `2` the coefficient of `x` or vice-versa? What is the result of `reduce(np.polymul, a)` by itself? What is the result of `reduce(np.polymul, a[1:])` by itself? Can you reproduce this with a smaller example? E.g., if you remove the last polynomial in `a`, does the problem still produce? What about removing the last two? More? Does it reproduce with simpler polynomials, say with all small integer coefficients?

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, I've updated the question with more details, and I was expecting accuracy of `1e-5`,  and it starts to break with `a[:8]` @EricPostpischil

Comment: The value of the polynomial that is `reduce(np.polymul, a[1:])` at the point x = -77.48514702 is about −8.58•10^16. At that scale, the low bit in the floating-point format (presuming IEEE-754 “double precision” is used, which is common), has a value of 16. Then there are multiple rounding errors involved in all the arithmetic to compute the product polynomial and then its quotient, so it is no surprise there are large errors. That is just a first analysis of the problem. I do not have a solution; I have not worked with floating-point polynomials in this way.

Comment: I wonder if I add a big enough constant 100 to all the `a[i][1] `, would it help?

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to compute some combinatoric quantities using the help of polynomial. so getting the coefficients right is important to my solution. I'm aware one of the solution can be using rationals to represent `a`, but I'm wondering if there are any more tricks @EricPostpischil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a slightly complicated way to keep the product first and then divide structure.

By first employ `n` points and evaluate on `a`.

```py
xs = np.linspace(0, 1., 10) 
ys = np.array([np.prod(list(map(lambda r: np.polyval(r, x), a))) for x in xs])
```

then do the division on `ys` instead of coefficients.

```py
ys = ys/np.array([np.polyval(a[0], x) for x in xs])
```

finally recover the coefficient using polynomial interpolation with `xs` and `ys`

```py
from scipy.interpolate import lagrange
lagrange(xs, ys)
```

#### Found a second solution

```
b = a[:,::-1]
np.polydiv(reduce(np.polymul, b), b[0])[0][::-1]
```